# Denwer или Apache?

Tags: apache, веб-программирование, denwer, php

Мне очень лень копаться с Апачем поэтому я предпочитаю Денвер! Вот скажите мне, пользоваться сборкой это таки стремно и не true? А Устанавливать Апач прикручивать к нему пыхыпы это высшая степень мастерства?

Вопрос вот к чему: если приду я устраиваться на работу а меня спросят Апач ставить можешь? А мне что сразу бежать от туда или гордо заявить мол я Денвером пользуюсь? Подскажите мне неразумному что лучше и почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем корректно сопоставлять Denwer и Apache. Дело в том, что один является сборкой из веб-сервера, php и mysql, а второй - только веб-сервером. Грубо говоря, для разработки разницы нет, Denwer сделан сборкой лишь для удобства. Но если вы пользуетесь этим удобством и не осознаете что, почему и как настроено в этой сборке - то это плохо, потому что воссоздать аналогичный контур без использования сборки и соответствующих знаний вы не сможете.

Веб-разработчика на собеседовании первым делом, скорее всего спросят про знания ООП, а не про конкретные технологии и думаю это будет важнейшим критерием при рассмотрении кандидатуры. Знаю это потому что вижу эту систему изнутри. Про веб-сервер вряд ли спросят, т.к. у работодателя для настройки контура скорее всего предусмотрена должность системного администратора, т.е. от веб разработчика настройку контура требовать не будут.

Answer (score 3):

Во 1вых, на кого устраиваться собираетесь? Если на **PHP разработчика**, то знать все премудрости установки сервера вам не обязательно. Но, уметь его настраивать удаленно, к примеру, в случае с “***Apache***” это файл **.htaccess** - было бы желательно.

**P.S.** Не нужно быть “Гуру”, что бы просто установить “***Apache***” и прикрутить к нему **PHP** модуль. Но там есть несколько нюансов. Скачайте. Установите.
В этом видео-уроке (в начале), рассматривается установка сервера ***Apache*** и прикрутка **PHP**:
 http://vk.com/video-21650259_158918463

Comment: Да ладно, какие видеоуроки, в ubuntu вообще просто:
sudo apt-get install tasksel
потом:
tasksel
и тыкаешь в нужные компоненты и все тебе примудрости установки.
Это всего лишь один способ установки. Автор удивится, когда узнает, что линуксы намного проще и понятней чем винды ;).

Answer (score 1):

Стоит начать с того, что Вам лень копаться)

Если Вы действительно хотите разбираться в своей области, то вам и без всяких мотиваций нужно хотеть разобраться в настройке сервера.

Мое мнение - если вы сидите под виндой и не дружите с Линуксом (никогда не использовали хотя бы Ubuntu или Linux Mint) - то можете особо не переживать за ручную настройку сервера - ибо это никому не нужно. Пользуйтесь дальше Денвером, а еще лучше - OpenServer'ом (отличный локальный сервер на все случаи жизни). Но если вы действительно хотите развиваться и становиться лучше - разбирайте Линукс и настраивайте окружение вручную. Опыта получите много. Тем более, что никакой уважающий себя веб-программист не будет работать с виндой.

Comment: даже вебразработчики на ASP? :)))) Интерпретатора ASP по линукс нету...

Comment: не в обиду разработчикам на ASP )) каноничная среда разработки на PHP - Линукс.

Comment: Поставить и настроить Arch )

Comment: никто не говорит, что настроить WAMP сильно отличается от LAMP - разница в установке самих программ и отсутствия надобности в добавлении прав и групп, так что "сидите под виндой" это глупо, уже не первый год работаю под виндой и под линуксом, нужно все уметь, тем более что сталкиваюсь с тем, что во многих компаниях винда это корпоративный стандарт (к сожелению или нет)

Comment: > Тем более, что никакой уважающий себя веб-программист не будет работать с виндой. 
Странный стереотип, откуда он появился? А если вам нужно узнать как из под винды будет работать ваше приложение или о кросс-платформенности уважающий себя веб-разработчик заботиться не станет?

Comment: @Андрей Таланин в большинстве случаев известно на какой платформе будет работать сайт, и если это php/nodejs/ruby/python/итд то 90% это будет linux, зачем при этом проверять как продукт будет себя вести на винде мне лично непонятно, если это opensource, то пользователи винды(если таковые будут) сами или починят или скинут багрепорт.

Answer (score 0):

Если будешь устраиваться в вэб разработку, то базовые навыки настройки вэб стека на сервере тебе будет огромный плюс. А если хочешь развиваться в этой сфере дальше, то эти знания обязательны.